# How to fix multiple execution when using jquery onclick and mouseup event to detect long press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which opens bootstrap modal when click on `div` element, everything is working fine on my computer, but some time on mobile when i click on the `div` it will show css focus around the element without executing the function in `onclick` method till i click on it the second time. So i tried using the below code to detect any click on the element except long pressing which i thing it will help. All works fine when i click once the function execute but always execute multiple time and it has ajax request inside which also send multiple time.

```js
var longpress = 3000;
var start;
 
$(document).on( 'mousedown focusIn',  '.openIt', function( event ) {
 start = new Date().getTime();
});

$(document).on( 'mouseleave focusOut', '.openIt', function( event ) {
 start = 0;
});
 
 $(document).on("click mouseup", '.openIt', function(event){
 if ( new Date().getTime() >= ( start + longpress )  ) {
  console.log(event.type, " is long press!");
 } else {
     //$.myfynctionHere({.......});
  console.log(event.type, " is short press!");
 }
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.openIt{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="openIt">Open Item</div>
```

Comment: Use only `onclick`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `mouseup` event from the event handler

```js
var longpress = 3000;
var start;
 
$(document).on( 'mousedown focusIn',  '.openIt', function( event ) {
 start = new Date().getTime();
});

$(document).on( 'mouseleave focusOut', '.openIt', function( event ) {
 start = 0;
});
 
 $(document).on("click", '.openIt', function(event){
 if ( new Date().getTime() >= ( start + longpress )  ) {
  console.log(event.type, " is long press!");
 } else {
     //$.myfynctionHere({.......});
  console.log(event.type, " is short press!");
 }
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.openIt{
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="openIt">Open Item</div>
```

Comment: Am wrong sorry, i deleted my comment, but what i want to as will removing the `click` still fix the problem on when i click on `div` sometime it only add focus without executing?

Comment: @Peter what do you mean? I don't understand

Comment: I mean when i try to execute my function this way is because sometimes on mobile when i click on `open item`, it will only add css focus without executing the function to open, till i click the second time. That why i try to detect any click on the element to open my item

Comment: @Peter I've updated my answer. You can remove `mouseup` to be sure that it works on mobile.